# How do I get my picture imported into my stackexchange profile from gravatar?

Tags: support, stackexchange, profile-page

I've already setup an account with gravatar, and uploaded a picture on it... but it's not showing up here in the stackexchange... Is there a step that I have overlooked?

Comment: Did you remember to use the e-mail address associated with your Gravatar account as the e-mail address in your profile?

Comment: Ah yes... now it it appearing... I guess it just took a while for it to show up.  Thanks for the reply though :)

Answer (score 2):

Just so this question is answered:

In order to use a Gravatar on an SE site, one should make sure that the e-mail address associated with the Gravatar account is the same e-mail address that you used in your SE account.

If you have recently changed your Gravatar, it can take a few minutes before it takes effect. Some patience is needed.